# How to record a video Only 2 min in titanium

Tags: android, titanium, android-video-player, video-player

I have tried recording a video for only 1 min with Titanium in Android using this function:

```
var intent = Titanium.Android.create Intent({action : 'android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE'})
```

and I've set duration limit with `intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 10000)`like in core android, but this property is not working in Titanium.So how can I set video recording duration in Titanium???

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the right thing.. You are just missing that

> intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 10000)

takes seconds, not mili-seconds.

Therefore it should be

```
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can record the video then check the video duration after by getDuration() method

Comment: Do you mean checking after the record was done? How does this answer the question? If you meant something else, please make it clear.